# Removing Windows and Ubuntu recovery partitions (BURG)

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I have Ubuntu and Windows installed on my computer and I'm using BURG boot loader. At the moment I have 4 entries in the boot menu, Ubuntu, Ubuntu recovery, Windows recovery and windows. This is quite confusing and doesn't look good, so I'd prefer to have only the "real" OS entries on the list.

So how could I hide these recovery partitions?

And if I hide the Ubuntu recovery entry, am I able to boot to the recovery partition somehow later if needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is what is known as "folded mode".

Run

```
sudo burg-emu
```

in the terminal. This will open a window showing you what your current burg setup is (nice because you don't have to reboot). If you press F1 to view a list of keys you can press, you'll see the f key is set to toggle folded mode. Try pressing f and see if it makes your burg look nicer.

I believe you have to run

```
sudo update-burg
```

to save changes. Btw you can change theme/resolution there too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did the job for Ubuntu recovery partition. However, Windows Recovery Environment still has its entry which I'd like to hide. Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: I would start by looking at the grub files (can't remember the new name since new grub was released). In there there's a section with all the OSes, I believe you can manuall remove entries from it.

Comment: If any OSes still show in folding mode, run `gksu gedit /boot/burg/burg.cfg` to delete the WinRE from the boot menu.  Unfortunately, editing from burg.cfg is necessary because Windows entries are put there by os-prober.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Max's answer, you can group the windows recovery and normal partitions together by running `sudo gedit /boot/burg/burg.cfg` and adding `--group group_win` at the end of the Windows declarations similar to how the Ubuntu ones are done (ie after `--class os` and before the open bracket).

The group name can be anything, so should another OS misbehave in this screen, you can just add another group.

(P.S. I know this is a mega bump, but I can't seem to find this anywhere else, and thought someone else would find it useful)